# Set attribute by id

Tags: import, products

I import products to magento programmatically. And I have some attributes with different options. For example, I want to import the manufacturer 'name2' so:

attribute code = 'manufacturer'
options:
'name1' id=1
'name2' id=2
'name3' id=3

Then, I check it in a foreach and I get that the id is 2. And I put:

```
$product->setData('manufacturer',$id);
...
$product->save();
```

But it not works. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

try like that

```
$product->setData('manufacturer', $id)->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'manufacturer');
```